# Не обрабатывается скрипт JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis-10

Приветствую.

Собственно проблема следующая,  после переезда сайта с apache на iis 10, перестал отрабатываться скрипт JQuery. Причём на apache всё работает идеально.

При вводе неправильного url, пользователя перебрасывает на сгенерируемую 404 страницу. В iis не происходит отображение содержимого данной страницы, всё висит на одном месте. Вот ссылка на страницу, где не отрабатывает скрипт (http://www.access.repair/404.html). В консоле выпадает ошибка GET access.repair/ajax/404.html?_=1490257623612 406 (Not Acceptable). Подскажите, может что то в iis необходимо добавить? Спасибо.

Comment: а разве `404.html` это не специально сгенерированная страница?

Comment: Она генерируется при вводе ошибки в url.

Comment: тогда я не понял вопрос. Пользователя перебрасывает или нет?

Comment: Да перебрасывает (пользователь попадает на 404.html), дальше на странице должно отобразится содержимое, но этого не происходит, просто всё виснет. В apache такого не было. В консоле выпадает ошибка GET http://www.access.repair/ajax/404.html?_=1490257623612 406 (Not Acceptable).

Comment: Вот это как раз надо в вопрос добавить.

Comment: Мой косяк, не совсем точно сформулировал вопрос. Исправил.

Comment: Я имел ввиду про ошибку _406_

Comment: Для начала уберите `<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    (function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|Mac OS X/i))
    window.location.replace("http://www.access.repair/mobile.html");
    }
    )();
    //]]>
    </script>` потому как оно впадает в бесконечный круговой редирект

Comment: Убрал, не помогло.